# python how to populate a list in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will receive inputs, run some calculations and store them in a list before adding the elements of the list. but I keep getting the error:
 wh_list = wh_list.append(wh)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

code:

```
wh_list = []
u = len(wh_list)
if u <= 1:
    while True:
        inp = input("Y or N:")
        B = int(input("B value:"))
        C = int(input("C value:"))
        D = int(input("D value:"))
        wh = B * C * D
        wh = int(wh)
        wh_list = wh_list.append(wh)
        if inp == "Y":
            break
else:
    Ewh = sum(wh_list)
    print(Ewh)
```

Comment: Please add a plain python tag, not just python-3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` changes the list and returns `None`. Thus,

```
wh_list = wh_list.append(wh)
```

will

- append `wh` to `wh_list`
- assign `None` to `wh_list`

In the next iteration, it will break, as `wh_list` is a list no more.

Instead, write just

```
wh_list.append(wh)
```

Comment: Could you help me dupe hammer the question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did vote, when you posted the dupe... Not sure how to explicitly hammer it.

Comment: I probably added the tag only after you voted. Oh well. Hopefully someone else will come along and do it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah, that's probably it.